# How to draw a scrollable menu in the html5 canvas with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

So I'm creating this crafting menu sort of thing in my html5 game and i came across this problem where when there are too many crafting recipes, the crafting recipes will not be shown as my menu is too small to fit them all.
Is there a way to make the menu scrollable?

(I only want the menu itself to be scrollable and not the entire canvas to be scrollable)

Examples:

[image: crafting menu example].
[image: more crafting menu example]

Thank you :)

Edit:

```
<canvas onscrcoll='scroll()'></canvas>
```

This doesn't work

Nevermind I have already found the answer(

```
document.addEventListener('wheel',ScrollFunction)
```

Comment: I will support your Q if you provide some source code of your attempt.

Answer (score -1):

You will need to exact place of the menu in the `canvas`, for example between upperleft corner (X1, Y1) and lower right corner (X2, Y2). If a scroll event happens in the canvas, you will need to handle it, otherwise ignore the scroll, like:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="1024" height="768" onscroll="canvasScroll()"></canvas>
```

You will need to implement your own logic though.

Comment: Um... It doesn't work. Scrolling will only work if there's a scrollbar